# Java save/load on game - will not compile. (cannot find method)

Tags: java, serialization, load, save

I have created a save and a load function for my game,however, it refuses to load.  (This is my first dealing with save/restore functionality).

It *seems* to save and by that i mean a 'minesweepersavestate.ser' file appears in my folder but there is an error loading, the error lies in the  for (Enumeration e = b.keys(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) { line.  It wont compile because it says 'cannot find sysmbol - method keys', i have imported java.util.*.

Could anyone tell me where my error is so i can get these functions working, thank you.

```
public void saveGame(){

    GameBoard b = new GameBoard();
    try {
        System.out.println("Creating File/Object output stream...");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("minesweepersavestate.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

        System.out.println("Writing GameBoard Object...");
        out.writeObject(b);

        System.out.println("Closing all output streams...\n");
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Class not found\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("no");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}

public void LoadBoard()
{
    GameBoard b = null;
    try {

        System.out.println("Creating File/Object input stream...");

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("minesweepersavestate.ser");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

        System.out.println("Loading GameBoard Object...");
        b = (GameBoard)in.readObject();

        System.out.println("Closing all input streams...\n");
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Class not found\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Printing out loaded elements...");
    for (Enumeration e = b.keys(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        Object obj = e.nextElement();
        System.out.println("  - Element(" + obj + ") = " + b.get(obj));
    }
```

Comment: Please post the source code of `GameBoard` or at least the signature of it's `keys` method.

Comment: You are calling the method `keys()` on a variable of type `GameBoard`. This is your class. Does it have such a method? Please provide that class.

Comment: `keys()` is probably a private method, you should be able to figure this one out yourself just by looking at IDE warnings and tips.

Comment: Just a note: though your `catch` blocks print the stack trace, they do not stop the execution of the program. So even if you have an exception, you will get to the `for` loop, which means `b` might be null there. You should either exit/return at the exceptions or protect your `for` loop against `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Ah that'll be it, I do not have a keys method I got this from a tutorial so I assumed key() was a built in method. I'll need to take a closer look at the tutorial again.  Thanks